# gdb won't accept user input

Tags: c, linux, assembly, gdb

I'm currently following [this video](http://www.securitytube.net/video/210) on how to work with assembly and gdb, using [this C program](http://code.securitytube.net/SimpleDemo.c), but I'm running into a problem. Here's what I do to compile and run gdb:

```
chiggins@host:~/assem$ gcc -ggdb -o SimpleDemo SimpleDemo.c
chiggins@host:~/assem$ gdb ./SimpleDemo
GNU gdb (Ubuntu/Linaro 7.4-2012.04-0ubuntu2) 7.4-2012.04
Copyright (C) 2012 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.  Type "show copying"
and "show warranty" for details.
This GDB was configured as "x86_64-linux-gnu".
For bug reporting instructions, please see:
<http://bugs.launchpad.net/gdb-linaro/>...
Reading symbols from /home/chiggins/assem/SimpleDemo...done.
(gdb) list
4       int add(int x, int y)
5       {
6               int z =10;
7
8               z = x + y;
9               return z;
10      }
11
12      main(int argc, char **argv)
13      {
(gdb)
14              int a = atoi(argv[1]);
15              int b = atoi(argv[2]);
16              int c;
17              char buffer[100];
18
19              gets(buffer);
20              puts(buffer);
21
22              c = add(a,b);
23
(gdb)
24              printf("Sum of %d+%d = %d\n",a, b, c);
25
26              exit(0);
27
28      }
(gdb) run 10 20
Starting program: /home/chiggins/assem/SimpleDemo 10 20
demo
```

Now from where I have "demo" typed at the end, that's where the program is supposed to be accepting user input. But when I press return after typing enter, nothing happens. I can't ctrl+c out of the program, can't do anything. I end up having to kill the process from another session just so I can get control back. Any ideas why gdb is doing this, or what I might be doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: I think that is correct because the program name is usually argv[0].  This is a weird C convention.

Comment: Have you tried using GDB to step through the program to see where it is getting hung up?

Comment: @VanDarg - No, just because it works in the video, and I've been following everything character by character.

Comment: @Chiggins: Well, I would start with that. GDB is a very powerful debugger. Create breakpoints at various locations, and wait to see if the program makes it there. For example, create a breakpoint at line 19 and 20. Also, does the program produce the same result if arguments are not passed? Does the program run directly from command-line(i.e., not within GDB)?

Comment: @Chiggins: Why doesn't main have a return type? If this is the source I am surprised it compiles.

Comment: @VanDarg - Like I said, just following the video character by character, his code didn't have it. Also, it'll run outside gdb. I set a breakpoint at 17 and it didn't get that far. gdb just hangs like it has been, doesn't stop the program at the breakpoint.

Comment: @Chiggins: Then create a breakpoint earlier and see what happens. Also, I would make sure main has a return type and that it returns 0 upon successful execution.

Comment: Did a return 0, added an int return type, set a breakpoint at 14. Still the same thing.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/12713/discussion-between-vandarg-and-chiggins)

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure why that doesn't work for you; it works as expected here...

Still, I find it easier to run programs performing interactive I/O in a separate terminal, and perhaps it will help you.

In one terminal,

```
$ gdbserver --multi localhost:4242
listening on port 4242
```

and in another,

```
$ gdb ./SimpleDemo
(gdb) target extended-remote localhost:4242
Remote debugging using localhost:4242
(gdb) run 10 20
```

Back to the terminal running `gdbserver`,

```
Remote debugging from host 127.0.0.1
Process ./SimpleDemo created; pid=PID
demo
demo
Sum of 10+20 = 30

Child exited with status 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to have user input during the program? If you simply want to set command line arguments at the beginning you can just say set args ... where you can give the arguments as you would during the course of the program.

Comment: The program accepts command line arguments, that's why in my run command I have a "10 20" at the end. I believe the guy doing the video has a reason for the gets() and puts() in the code that'll be explained in a future video, so I wouldn't want that to be in the arguments.

Comment: before typing run, trying typing set args 10 20.

This might be helpful too:

http://www.delorie.com/gnu/docs/gdb/gdb_19.html

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this?

```
gdb --args ./SimpleDemo 10 20
```

Answer (score 0):

Use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> instead of the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key.

Comment: Why would that be different?  In "cooked" mode in a Linux `konsole` (KDE) window, control+enter sends the same newline character as unmodified enter.  (I ran `hexdump -C` with its input from the terminal.)  Does readline get different raw input?

Comment: You answer is correct for X-Windows because it can see the raw keyboard input.  The problem is the terminal window.  There is no way to properly represent the difference between ENTER, SHIFT-ENTER, and CTRL-ENTER so they all reduce to ^M.  Read more here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/536352/ctrl-enter-shift-enter-and-enter-are-interpreted-as-the-same-key